# How Do I Use 'cp' to Overwrite Files?

Tags: terminal, command-line, script

Using a shell script or Terminal, how do I overwrite files that may or may not be present. I looked at man page for cp, it said use the -f argument to force overwrite. But, it does nothing.

```
$ cp -f /path/to/source/file.txt /path/to/target
```

Or is there another option to overwrite files using the common in-built command line tools in OS X?

Comment: It works for me. What is it doing instead of overwriting when you try it?

Comment: If you don't have permission to overwrite the target file, this will fail. If you really want to overwrite a target file, you can use `sudo` at the beginning of the command. But use with caution!

Comment: @Gordon Davisson: What's it doing? nothing. It will only copy the files to the target directory if I `mv` them or `rm` them.

Comment: @Daniel Lawson:  Without using `sudo` I can use `mv` or `rm` to move or remove files before using `cp`. Using `sudo cp` makes no difference.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser.

Comment: Does [`set +o noclobber`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clobbering) solve your issue ?

Comment: (for posterity) use `\cp` to make sure you are using non-aliased `cp`

Answer (score 19):

I'm stumped as to why cp is behaving this way if there's no alias involved. However, there is a quick-dirty-and-dangerous utility provided for this exact situation: `yes`. You can use it to pipe a continuous stream of affirmatives into any command that gives you confirmation prompts (you can use it to send any text, but the default is "y").

`yes | cp foo bar` will execute the cp command and bypass all confirmation prompts.

Answer (score 10):

It might be caused by a command alias.

To call `cp` directly you can use `/bin/cp src dest`

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. I was under the impression that explicitly specifying -f would override -i in the alias, but I checked and it does not. The poster should find out whether they have cp aliased (type `alias cp`). They can change the alias in their profile or use /bin/cp as suggested.

Comment: I am using default `cp` as Apple provided it.

Comment: @octern: `roger$ alias cp 
-bash: alias: cp: not found`

Comment: I had to use /bin/cp I don't know why.

Comment: I might be way too late but for people coming from search engine I was able to see if the command had any alias to it by doing `type cp`. And it indeed did.

Answer (score 2):

```
rm foo/bar/destination && cp source foo/bar/destination
```

First you remove (`rm`) the destination, then if successful (`&&`) you do your copying. When removing a folder, please remember to add `-r` to `rm` (`rm -r`).

Answer (score 2):

It's more simple. If you use a backslash before your command it will overwrite files without prompting.

```
$ \cp /path/to/source/file.txt /path/to/target
```

Comment: Just to explain why it does work: the backslash before command will force OS to use a real command instead of its alias. So you don't have to comment anything in your aliases.

Answer (score 1):

I also had an alias messing up with -f, call cp directly from /bin and all is fine, having an alias that prevents accidental overwrites/removals by default is pretty good, so best not remove it.

> .# alias
>
> alias cp='cp -i'

like already stated, the -i flag superceedes -f, which wouldn't allow below command to perform as intended.

> .# /bin/cp -fauv src dst